# Implementing a video file in XCode 4.3.2

Tags: ios5, video, xcode4.3

Was wondering how to include a video file in a controller. I want to include text in the controller as well so if the user clicks on the video then it should pop out. I am not sure which view to include in the storyboard as well. Ideally I want to make a rectangle which would be below the text. This rectangle when clicked on would launch the video.

Here is an example image of what I am trying to do

[image]

Comment: This documentation seems to be still relevant for basic video playback: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingVideo/UsingVideo.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH3

Comment: I read this, not sure how it would look like in the storyboard though